# Knockout.JS labels not working inside foreach

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, laravel-blade

I have used the HTML5 label 'for' attribute in the past, and it works well in that you can click it and it will change the focus to the relevant form item. However, in this case where the name of each item is partially determined by its index, the label does not seem to respond to clicks.

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind='foreach: people'>
    <div class="personWell">  
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for':'personsObserved['+ $index()+'][name]'}" class="content-label">Name</label> 
        <input type="text" data-bind="attr: {'name':'personsObserved['+ $index()+'][name]'}, value: name" required placeholder="Person Name"></input>

        <label data-bind="attr: {'for':'personsObserved['+ $index()+'][company]'}" class="content-label">Company</label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="attr: {'name':'personsObserved['+ $index()+'][company]'}, value: company" required placeholder="Company Name"></input>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-bind='visible: $root.people().length > 1, click: $root.removePerson'>Delete</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Outputted Source**

```
<label data-bind="attr: {'for':'personsObserved['+ $index()+'][name]'}" class="content-label" for="personsObserved[0][name]">Name</label>

<input type="text" data-bind="attr: {'name':'personsObserved['+ $index()+'][name]'}, value: name" required="" placeholder="Person Name" name="personsObserved[0][name]">
```

As you can see, the 'for' and 'name' attributes match. But clicking on the label does nothing.

Comment: Are you trying to resolve "personsObserved[0][name]"? Because that's just a string you made, pretty sure that won't be executed. You might as well just do 'person' + $index().

Comment: Also, I always thought that this was implemented using 'id' instead of 'name'.

Comment: The name computation does execute properly, as is shown in the outputted source code. All my previously working labels have had the name field referenced in their 'for'

Comment: It doesn't look like it's executing it. I would expect to see the name of the first 'person' in your 'personsObserved' array if it was.

Comment: Oh I see the confusion. `personsObserved[0][name]` is exactly what I want. The only thing that changes is the number (id). That way when I serialize it I can say in this 0th object, it has a field called name.

Comment: I don't know how your other fields are working. I've only ever seen it done with 'id'. Did you try it?

Comment: in the `for` attribute you have to provide the **ID** of the element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label: for
The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element.

Comment: Can you provide us with the person array data you are using to bind to the view please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for attribute must specify the ID in HTML 5... it flat-out won't work with the name attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: You're absolutely right. The reason why it seemed to be working before was because I was using blade syntax to generate the labels and inputs and it automatically inserted IDs.